# Autocomplete uses sql "Like" query, but returns every result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, json, razor

My code :

```
var db = Database.Open("dbase");
var term = Request.Form["username"] + "%";
var sql = "SELECT * from Users where Username LIKE @0";
var result = db.Query(sql, term);
var data = result.Select(p => new{label = p.username});
Json.Write(data, Response.Output);
```

And the form :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#username').autocomplete({source:'getProducts'});
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <label for="username">Enter Username: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
        </form>
```

The problem : This process is ran every time a user types a character into a text box. No matter what character is typed, every single username in the database is returned. I assume the problem lies in my SQL query ?

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Why are you selecting `*` if you only use one column?

Comment: Have you checked `term` in the debugger?

Comment: What's the value of your sql string before you query the db? My guess is that you're not getting your username so your sql looks like "SELECT * from Users where username LIKE %" which will give you everything.

Comment: @SLaks, I will be using the rest of the data...when it works! :)

Comment: @Dan That seems to be the issue. Thanks very much for the response. I have updated my code now to show my form, which is contained in a different file.

Comment: Ah yes, I am so stupid! Of course the Request.Form() construct needs to be on the same page. Does anyone know what I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Request.QueryString["term"]` instead of `Request.Form["username"]`.

This is based on the documentation at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/. Look for the quoted string `"term"` on that page.

Comment: Why do you suggest that? Where in any of the UI code do you see anything with the name or id "term"?

Comment: It works because your function needs to use the URL parameter `term` for the jQuery UI autocomplete. You're not actually submitting a form at this point so there will be nothing in `Request.Form`.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to make sure that request.Form["username"] is not empty and hat you are not always sending LIKE '%'

Comment: This certainly seems to be the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @mreyeros This is sound advice, but not the answer. Please move it into the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts:

- You could prevent the execution until a certain input length has been reached.
- Or introduce a time constraint, meaning that only after a certain about of time has gone by without additional input the code is executed
- Or just add a search button that executes the code rather than executing it on key press events

Comment: Although a great tip, I don't think this is what he is looking for. I thikn he is asking why is every result being returned, instead of those matching ntzi%